# while loop won't terminate with a logical conditional

Tags: c, loops, comparison, while-loop, conditional-statements

This loop won't terminate if I add an OR conditional statement. If one is false, then it should terminate.

//global var

```
int x = 100;
    char *n= malloc (64);

void add(void)
{       

    do      
    {
        printf("Would you like to add 1? (y/n) ");
        fgets(n, 64, stdin);
            //removes newline
        n[strlen(n)-1] = '\0';
            x++;
    }       
//if I add || (x!=100) it keeps looping me even if I press "n"
//otherwise without it it works fine

        while((strncmp(n, "n", 1) != 0) || x!=100 );

        free(n);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of your loop, you're doing `x++`. Once you hit the while condition, `x == 101`, so your loop never terminates, `x` never equals 100 when the condition is being checked.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
while((strncmp(n, "n", 1) != 0) && x != 100);
```

Which would terminated the loop if either of the two conditions is false.

`&&` is the 'logical and' operator, `||` is the 'logical or' operator. To help you keep track, you can use a [Truth Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to help you sort out the details. Logical and is the same as logical conjunction and logical or is the same as logical disjunction.

Comment: Oh.. it seems I mixed it up. Thanks everyone for clarifying !

Comment: Keep in mind that the '&&' and '||' operators are so-called 'short-circuit' operators and will not evaluate the right-hand operand if the left-hand operand is sufficient to determine the outcome.  The results can be different from using single '&' or '|' when a function evaluation is performed in the expression, as is the case here.  (Though in this case the function will get called since it is the first operand).

Comment: Ok, by entering n, the compiler will not even check the right operand if I use &&

Comment: @user1615805 With `&&`, if the first operand is false, it will not evaluate the second. With `||` if the first operand is true, it will not evaluate the second.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop will execute as long as the entire condition evaluates to `1`, or true. If `x` is *never* `100`, then the logical OR in your condition will *always* be true, because one of it's operands is true.

`x` begins at `100`, and each time through the loop, you increment `x`. So before you ever test `x` in the loop condition, it is greater than 100 - it's 101 - and always increases.

Comment: If i press n then the whole condition should be false and exit? But it won't exit

Comment: @user1615805 no it's an OR statement. So even if you press _n_, as long as `x` is something other than `100`, the loop won't terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You picked the wrong boolean operator.  If you type n, and x is equal to 10, the while condition simplifies like this:

while((strncmp(n, "n", 1) != 0) || x!=100 );
while((0 != 0) || (10!=100) );
while(0 || 1)
while(1)

Since each comparison is already a NOT, you want && instead of ||

Answer (score 1):

Checking numeric equality to terminate a loop is usually a bad idea.  You want to check for a range of values, e.g., `x < 100`.

Hence, the classic `for` loop test is **`i < n`** and not `i != n`.

I only terminate loops with equality when the variable is a boolean type.

Comment: like this? while((strncmp(n, "n", 1) != 0) && x < 100 && x >= 0 )

Comment: If you require that the loop continue while x is less than 100 *and* non-negative, then yes.  It's also good practice to surround the expressions between conditional operators with parenthesis for readability.

Answer (score 0):

the condition x!=100 is never going to be false, since x is already incremented to 101 when the first do while is executed 
so to make the statement false u should use && in place of ||